# Quadratic Program subproblem, what is the difference between $d$ and $d_k$?

Tags: quadratic-programming

What is the difference between $d$ and $d_k$? 
I have the explanation:
Quadratic Program subproblem  formulated as 
\ \
 \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{d}{\text{minimize}} & & \frac{1}{2} d^T H_k d+\nabla f(x_k)^T d \\
& \text{subject to} & & \nabla g_i(x_k)^Td+g_i(x_k)\leq 0 \; \;i = 1, \ldots, m\\
& & &  \nabla h_j(x_k)^Td+h_j(x_k)=0 \; \;j = 1, \ldots, n\\
%&&& x_k^{low}\leq x\leq x_k^{high}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where the Hessian is positive definite, to ensure a minimum is found. 
Every iteration $k$ computes a new Hessian $H_k$ and solve the corresponding subproblem. The search direction $d_k$ is used to chose the next point, which is closer to the local minima, as follows
$$x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha_k d_k.$$

Why does the $d$ in the formulation not have the index $d_k$? What is the difference between $d$ and $d_k$?

Comment: Could it be that $d_k$ is the search direction and $d$ is a vector containing the directions in the point $x_k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been stated as you suggest, however, the author in question has chosen to do otherwise.

It is clear that in this context, the search direction $d_k$ is the argmin, i.e., the optimal value of $d$, in the Quadratic Program subproblem.  It's as simple as that.